# Exibir e esconder div após filtro com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Olá.

Tenho o seguinte filtro:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search| filter:selectedCategories| filter:selectedType| filter:selectedDate| orderBy:'+id':true| limitTo: 10">
```

Quer colocar o texto "Últimos usuários" quando a página for carregada e quero que ele não apareça quando o usuário usar o filtro.

Alguma ideia?

edit:

```
<div ng-app="testeApp">
      <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('testeApp',[]);
            myApp.controller('testeController', function($scope){
                  $scope.users=[
                        {id:1, name:"Fulano", startdate:'janeiro', categories:'normal', type:'xpto'},
                  ];
            });
      </script>
</div>


<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="text-input" placeholder="Nome, Cidade, País, Continente" autofocus />
<select ng-model="selectedCategories">
    <option value="">-- Categoria --</option>
    <option value='normal'>Normal</option>
</select>
  <select class="type" ng-model="selectedType">
    <option value="">-- Tipo --</option>
    <option value='xpto'>xpto</option>
</select>

  <select class="data" ng-model="selectedDate">
    <option value="">-- Data --</option>
    <option value="janeiro">janeiro</option>
    <option value="fevereiro">fevereiro</option>
  </select>
</form>

<h3 ng-if="!search">Últimos usuários adicionados</h3>
```

Comment: `<span ng-if="!!search">Últimos usuários</span>` ?

Comment: valeu pela resposta, funcionou assim: `<span ng-if="!search">Últimos usuários</span>`
Agora, como faço para a mesma coisa acontecer com os demais filtros? Tentei usando OR `<span ng-if="!search || !selectedCategories || !selectedType || !selectedDate">Últimos usuários</span>` e não funcionou

Comment: Vou confessar que foi no chute (calculado, mas chute. =) ). Isso porque eu supus que `search` fosse apenas um objeto. Se `selectedCategories`, por exemplo, for um objeto registrado (um filter do angular) essa mecânica pode não funcionar. Poderia postar um pouco mais do seu código?

Comment: @carlostiago Você pode [edit] sua publicação e adicionar esse tipo de informação nela mesma. Além de ficar mais legível e melhor formatado, os comentários servem pra outro propósito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um *alias* para o resultado da sua cadeia de filtros:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search|filter:selectedCategories as filteredUsers">
```

O Angular copia o valor final da coleção filtrada para o `$scope`. Você pode então comparar o original com o final:

```
<span ng-if="users.length == filteredUsers.length">Últimos usuários</span>
```